# Disabling Postgraphile automatically generated mutations?

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

Taken from `postgraphile` documentation

> PostGraphile automatically generates CRUD Mutations for you; but it's rare that these will cover all your needs - and many people just disable them outright.

Is there any drawbacks or concerns of using automatically generated CRUD mutations from postgraphile apart from the fact that they might not cover all needs?

Comment: we have the very same question - did you get any answer on this ?